# getWindowHandles() not working in firefox 58.The focus remains on parent tab and does not transfer to next tab

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, window-handles, webdriverwait

I am starting to learn how to handle multiple tabs in a browser using     Selenium with Java. looks like my code below is not working.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    public class HandlingWindows {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {

        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        String parent= driver.getWindowHandle();
        System.out.println("Parent Window is"+parent);

        //Get Data Policy
        WebElement we= driver.findElement(By.linkText("Data Policy"));
        //Click Data Policy link
        we.click();
        //Create an arrayList
        ArrayList<String> s1= new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());


         for(String s2:s1)
           {


            if(!(s2.equalsIgnoreCase(parent)))
              {
               driver.switchTo().window(s2);
               Thread.sleep(5000);
               System.out.println(driver.getWindowHandle());
               System.out.println("get title of window"+driver.getTitle());
              }
             }
    }

}
```

Please let me know how can I display the title 'Data Policy' without using 
getWindowHandles().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getWindowHandles()` works pretty fine but before invoking `getWindowHandles()` you have to induce *WebDriverwait* as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
String parent= driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println("Parent Window is"+parent);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Data Policy")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
Set<String> s1= driver.getWindowHandles();
for(String s2:s1)
{
    if(!parent.equalsIgnoreCase(s2))
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(s2);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println(driver.getWindowHandle());
            System.out.println("get title of window"+driver.getTitle());
        }
}
```

Console Output :

```
Parent Window is4294967297
4294967303
get title of windowData Policy
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `Thread.sleep(3000);` after clicking on Data Policy link.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class HandlingWindows {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        //D:\new folde backup\Selenium_project\seleniumproject\testNG_practice\driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./driver/geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        String parent = driver.getWindowHandle();
        System.out.println("Parent Window is" + parent);

        // Get Data Policy
        WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Data Policy"));
        // Click Data Policy link
        we.click();
        // Create an arrayList
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        ArrayList<String> s1 = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        System.out.println(s1);
        for (String s2 : s1) {

            if (!(s2.equalsIgnoreCase(parent))) {
                driver.switchTo().window(s2);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                System.out.println(driver.getWindowHandle());
                System.out.println("get title of window" + driver.getTitle());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Output:-

```
Parent Window is4294967297
[4294967297, 4294967301]
4294967301
get title of windowData Policy
```