# Unable to focus on new tab in firefox when clicking on the link that opens a new tab using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

```
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/footer/div/div[1]/section/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[9]/div/div/a")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
print(driver.title)
```

The xpath mentioned is that of a link. In the above code after  driver.execute_script is executed the link is opened in a new tab but driver.title still shows the title of the old tab as a result a new element in the new tab could not be identified. Can someone help me here please.

Selenium version used: 3.11.0
Firefox version used: 47.0.2
geckodriver version used: 0.14

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getWindowHandles() not working in firefox 58.The focus remains on parent tab and does not transfer to next tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49142180/getwindowhandles-not-working-in-firefox-58-the-focus-remains-on-parent-tab-and)

Answer (score 0):

If after clicking on next button, Page opens in a new tab then you have to switch the focus of WebDriver to that window.

```
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
# Click on next button on Page 1.
# Opens a new tab
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to_window(window_after)

#performs some operations on Page 2.
print(driver.title)
driver.close()

driver.switch_to.window(window_before )
```

Comment: tried your suggestion but got error    tabs = driver.getWindow_Handles
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'getWindow_Handles'

Comment: No it didn't work. The thing is the code I have shared worked fine with Chrome but not in Firefox. In Chrome it is able to switch the tab to the new one but in Firefox it is failing.

Comment: elm=driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/footer/div/div[1]/section/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[9]/div/div/a")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elm)
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
    print(driver.current_url)

Comment: I tried the above code and driver.current_url is returning "about:blank"

Comment: Because "html/body/footer/div/div[1]/section/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[9]/div/div/a  this Xpath has some serious issue .