# Firefox driver not navigating to new tab

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am facing a problem when I run selenium tests on firefox driver. the issue is that the driver is not navigating to new tab. it open the tab, however the flow is not shifting. these are the dependencies I used in the pom :

```
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
          <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
  <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
          <version>LATEST</version>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
              <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
              <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
              <version>2.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

and this is the instance of firefox driver i am creating-

```
FirefoxDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

this is the import-

```
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.FirefoxDriverManager;
```

this is the piece of code I used to navigate to the new window.

```
 public void switchToNewWindow() {
        parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for (String windowHandle : handles) {
            if (!windowHandle.equals(parentWindow)) {
                driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
                driver.manage().window().maximize();

            }
        }
    }
```

the tests runs fine on chrome browser with out any issues.

this is the version of the firefox browser-

```
Version 61.0.2 (64-bit)
```

this is the error message. the locator it failed to detect is in the new tab, which the driver failed to switch to-

```
  Testing started at 16:03 ...
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java" -Dorg.jetbrains.run.directory=C:\Users\rajeshg\IdeaProjects\nxtier\src\test\Resources\com\unionstreet\NxTier\smokePack "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=52489:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\IdeaProjects\nxtier\target\test-classes;C:\Users\rajeshg\IdeaProjects\nxtier\target\classes;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\23.0\guava-23.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.0.18\error_prone_annotations-2.0.18.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.1\j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\animal-sniffer-annotations\1.14\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\jayway\restassured\rest-assured\2.9.0\rest-assured-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\groovy\groovy\2.4.4\groovy-2.4.4.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\groovy\groovy-xml\2.4.4\groovy-xml-2.4.4.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.1\httpclient-4.5.1.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpmime\4.5.1\httpmime-4.5.1.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-library\1.3\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\ccil\cowan\tagsoup\tagsoup\1.2.1\tagsoup-1.2.1.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\jayway\restassured\json-path\2.9.0\json-path-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\groovy\groovy-json\2.4.4\groovy-json-2.4.4.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\jayway\restassured\rest-assured-common\2.9.0\rest-assured-common-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\jayway\restassured\xml-path\2.9.0\xml-path-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\jayway\jsonpath\json-path\2.4.0\json-path-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.3\json-smart-2.3.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\net\minidev\accessors-smart\1.2\accessors-smart-1.2.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\5.0.4\asm-5.0.4.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-all\1.3\hamcrest-all-1.3.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\json-simple\json-simple\1.1.1\json-simple-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\io\github\bonigarcia\webdrivermanager\2.2.0\webdrivermanager-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.5\commons-io-2.5.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.0\gson-2.8.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\rauschig\jarchivelib\0.7.1\jarchivelib-0.7.1.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.9\commons-compress-1.9.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\jsoup\jsoup\1.10.2\jsoup-1.10.2.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\vimalselvam\cucumber-extentsreport\1.0.0\cucumber-extentsreport-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-java\1.2.3\cucumber-java-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\relevantcodes\extentreports\2.40.2\extentreports-2.40.2.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\xerial\sqlite-jdbc\3.8.11.1\sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.1.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\freemarker\freemarker\2.3.23\freemarker-2.3.23.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\apache\directory\studio\org.apache.commons.codec\1.8\org.apache.commons.codec-1.8.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-java\3.14.0\selenium-java-3.14.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\3.14.0\selenium-chrome-driver-3.14.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-edge-driver\3.14.0\selenium-edge-driver-3.14.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\3.14.0\selenium-firefox-driver-3.14.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-ie-driver\3.14.0\selenium-ie-driver-3.14.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-opera-driver\3.14.0\selenium-opera-driver-3.14.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\3.14.0\selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-safari-driver\3.14.0\selenium-safari-driver-3.14.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-support\3.14.0\selenium-support-3.14.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.8.15\byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.9\httpcore-4.4.9.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okhttp3\okhttp\3.10.0\okhttp-3.10.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okio\okio\1.14.1\okio-1.14.1.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.4\commons-lang3-3.4.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit\2.18\htmlunit-2.18.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.2\xalan-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\xalan\serializer\2.7.2\serializer-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit-core-js\2.17\htmlunit-core-js-2.17.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\xerces\xercesImpl\2.11.0\xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.4.01\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\nekohtml\nekohtml\1.9.22\nekohtml-1.9.22.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\cssparser\cssparser\0.9.16\cssparser-0.9.16.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\w3c\css\sac\1.3\sac-1.3.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-client\9.2.12.v20150709\websocket-client-9.2.12.v20150709.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-util\9.2.12.v20150709\jetty-util-9.2.12.v20150709.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-io\9.2.12.v20150709\jetty-io-9.2.12.v20150709.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-common\9.2.12.v20150709\websocket-common-9.2.12.v20150709.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-api\9.2.12.v20150709\websocket-api-9.2.12.v20150709.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\jtds\jtds\1.3.1\jtds-1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\xmlunit\xmlunit\1.6\xmlunit-1.6.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\sqlserver\mssql-jdbc\6.1.0.jre8\mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\azure\azure-keyvault\0.9.3\azure-keyvault-0.9.3.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\azure\azure-core\0.9.3\azure-core-0.9.3.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4.5\mail-1.4.5.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-client\1.13\jersey-client-1.13.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-core\1.13\jersey-core-1.13.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-json\1.13\jersey-json-1.13.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jettison\jettison\1.1\jettison-1.1.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.3-1\jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.2.2\jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\javax\xml\stream\stax-api\1.0-2\stax-api-1.0-2.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.2\jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.2\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-jaxrs\1.9.2\jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-xc\1.9.2\jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\azure\adal4j\1.0.0\adal4j-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\nimbusds\oauth2-oidc-sdk\4.5\oauth2-oidc-sdk-4.5.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\net\jcip\jcip-annotations\1.0\jcip-annotations-1.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\nimbusds\lang-tag\1.4\lang-tag-1.4.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\nimbusds\nimbus-jose-jwt\3.1.2\nimbus-jose-jwt-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.51\bcprov-jdk15on-1.51.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-junit\1.2.5\cucumber-junit-1.2.5.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-core\1.2.5\cucumber-core-1.2.5.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-html\0.2.3\cucumber-html-0.2.3.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-jvm-deps\1.0.5\cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.5.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\info\cukes\gherkin\2.12.2\gherkin-2.12.2.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\pdfbox\2.0.0\pdfbox-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\fontbox\2.0.0\fontbox-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\6.0.4\mysql-connector-java-6.0.4.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\de\redsix\pdfcompare\1.1.25\pdfcompare-1.1.25.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\typesafe\config\1.3.1\config-1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\dbunit\dbunit\2.5.4\dbunit-2.5.4.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml\3.14\poi-ooxml-3.14.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi\3.14\poi-3.14.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml-schemas\3.14\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlbeans\xmlbeans\2.6.0\xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\stax\stax-api\1.0.1\stax-api-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\github\virtuald\curvesapi\1.03\curvesapi-1.03.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\com\opencsv\opencsv\4.0\opencsv-4.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-text\1.1\commons-text-1.1.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.9.3\commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\3.14.0\selenium-api-3.14.0.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty\3.5.7.Final\netty-3.5.7.Final.jar;C:\Users\rajeshg\.IdeaIC2017.3\config\plugins\cucumber-java\lib\cucumber-jvm-formatter.jar" cucumber.api.cli.Main --plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvmSMFormatter --monochrome --name "^Adding pricing details to a newly created customer$" --glue com.unionstreet.support --glue com.unionstreet.NxTier.stepDefs.smokePack C:/Users/rajeshg/IdeaProjects/nxtier/src/test/Resources/com/unionstreet/NxTier/smokePack/NxTier_smokePack.feature
16:03:51.767 [main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Reading https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases to seek wires, geckodriver
16:03:52.126 [main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Latest version of wires, geckodriver is 0.21.0
16:03:52.157 [main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Downloader - Using binary driver previously downloaded C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\webdriver\geckodriver\win64\0.21.0\geckodriver.exe
16:03:52.157 [main] DEBUG io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Downloader - Target folder content: geckodriver.exe
16:03:52.157 [main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.Downloader - Using binary driver previously downloaded C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\webdriver\geckodriver\win64\0.21.0\geckodriver.exe
16:03:52.157 [main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Exporting webdriver.gecko.driver as C:\Users\rajeshg\.m2\repository\webdriver\geckodriver\win64\0.21.0\geckodriver.exe
1533827032298   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.21.0
1533827032314   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:27819
1533827032954   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\rajeshg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.DpjbO1o8RyAk"
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\rajeshg\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\rajeshg\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\rajeshg\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\rajeshg\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\rajeshg\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
1533827034578   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 52497
1533827034618   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Aug 09, 2018 4:03:54 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: DCompany_name (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:113)
  at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:283)
  at com.unionstreet.support.ElementUtils.sendText(ElementUtils.java:70)
  at com.unionstreet.com.unionstreet.NxTier.pages.NewBusinessCustomerPage.addCompanyInfoForNewBusinessCustomerCreatedWithDefaultContactTypes(NewBusinessCustomerPage.java:65)
  at com.unionstreet.NxTier.stepDefs.smokePack.NxTier_smokePack_stepDefs.iHaveAddedANewBusinessCustomer(NxTier_smokePack_stepDefs.java:79)
  at ✽.And I have added a new business customer(C:/Users/rajeshg/IdeaProjects/nxtier/src/test/Resources/com/unionstreet/NxTier/smokePack/NxTier_smokePack.feature:45)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.id: DCompany_name
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'TESTING001', ip: '10.1.8.93', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

any help would be much appreciated! 
thank you!

Comment: the answer on a similar post was to introduce a bit of patience in your switch method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49142180/getwindowhandles-not-working-in-firefox-58-the-focus-remains-on-parent-tab-and

Comment: PDFBox is at 2.0.11 currently (not related to your problem). 2.0.0 has two security risks.

Comment: Thanks for your message Loflin! I did consider putting sleep but refrained from doing so as it would slow down the test.

Answer (score 0):

1) First you need to retrieve opened tabs

```
List<String> tabs = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
```

2) open new tab

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open('/')");
```

3) navigate to the tab

```
driver.switchTo.window(tabs.get(index))
```

Answer (score -1):

100% working solution:

```
// open new tab
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.open()");
Thread.sleep(100); // wait to winHandles value increases. Without it will result in random nullPointerException at this point.

// go to tab with index i
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver();
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(i));
Thread.sleep(100);

// close tab
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.close()");
Thread.sleep(100);
```